# Using nopCommerce v3.50, and want to integrate Stripe plugin

Tags: stripe-payments, nopcommerce

When looking to integrate Stripe payment gateway into nopCommerce application, is version compatibility an issue? The nopCommerce I am working on is version 3.50, and I have found stripe plugins for uptill version 3.40 and 3.8.

On searching further, found for version 2.8 but still not for 3.50. I know this version is pretty old.. but any help/advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to contact the vendor of that platform and/or plugin to find out what is available to you.

Answer (score 0):

When using or installing plugins, nopCommerce requires matching the plugin's supported version to match the nopCommerce version. So if you want to install a plugin in nopCommerce 3.50 that plugin must have the SupportedVersions of 3.50.

If you have the Stripe payment plugin version for nopCommerce 3.40 you should be able to use that for nopCommerce 3.50 by editing and updating the `Description.txt` file. NopCommerce doesn't usually change much internally in minor releases. You can find the `Description.txt` file in the plugin's root folder. Open the file, change `SupportedVersions` from 3.40 to 3.50 and you should be good to use it.

Just to be on the safer side please keep in mind that, if the plugin doesn't work properly after updating the Description file, you may need to look for any nuget packages which the plugin is referencing that also needs update. Also from September 2019, a new regulation called Strong Customer Authentication (SCA) requires businesses in Europe to request additional authentication for online payments. In this case you may have to implement additional functionalities in your plugin.